# Javascript - webpage slideshow loop

Tags: javascript, loops, timer

New to javascript - could really use some help. Basically, I want to create a script that loads three different web pages in a loop. The first web page will load immediately after the file is open in the same tab. 4 minutes later, the second web page is loaded. 2 minutes after that, the third page. I would like the flexibility to change the time each page is up before loading the next.

Goals:
1) Upon opening the .html file, it directs you to URL1 in the SAME window and SAME tab that the HTML file is open. 
2) After 4 minutes, it re-directs you to URL2 (in the SAME tab/window).
3) After 2 minutes of URL2 open (5 minutes from start of script), it re-directs you to URL3 (in the SAME tab/window).
4) Loops the entire day until it is killed.

When I use "_html" after the URL, it opens in the same tab/window, but the next two URLs never load. I can only get it to work in separate tabs.

I've tried location.replace, location.assign with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>


    var url1 = "http://www.google.com";
    var url2 = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    var url3 = "http://www.engadget.com";


    function openWindow1()
    {
     window.open(url1);
    };
    openWindow1();


    setTimeout(openWindow2, 240000); //1 minute = 60000ms; 60000ms * 4 minutes = 240000ms
    function openWindow2()
    {
     window.open(url2);
    };

    setTimeout(openWindow3, 360000); 
//1 minute = 60000ms; 60000ms * 2 minutes = 120000ms; 120000ms (2 minutes) + 240000ms (4 minutes) = 360000ms (6 minutes)
    function openWindow3()
    {
     window.open(url3);
    };


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When your browser redirects a new page is loaded and the time-outs and the code they execute are lost. You might do this with an iFrame that occupies the whole screen and change the iFrame's `src` attribute in your time-out functions. This won't work for some big sites like Facebook and Google as they prohibit loading of their sites in iFrames.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there a reason why it still opens all the links with the script attached then? There's multiple timeouts, but all the pages load; they just open in new tabs.

Comment: If you're opening the pages in new tabs then the original page remains and the script will continue executing. I got the impression you wanted each new page to open in the same tab as the original page that has the script.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; I do want the new pages to open in the original tab. Thanks for the prompt responses.